# How does an Electric Solid Propellant rocket work?

Tags: fuel, solid-fuel, restartable-engine

I saw the section in Wikipedia about [Electric Solid propellants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-fuel_rocket#Electric_Solid_Propellants) but I can't figure out what *it really is*, and how it works. It sounds like a solid propellant rocket that you can start and stop multiple times by turning it ON and OFF - a restartable solid fuel rocket.

*How!?*

Are there any examples of this type of rocket being put to use? (*beyond self-validation*)

Comment: http://dsspropulsion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ESP_Safe_Micro_To_Macro-Website.pdf

Comment: @SF. $\text{Wow!}^N$ This would be phenomenal if it ever turns out to be save enough for a shared payload space full of nanosatellites. The article is a useful summary/survey, but I still don't know how it actually works. Is it a high voltage radial discharge localized across the exposed surface? It works in vacuum? For a small engine, would the electrical power be Watts or kilo Watts?

Comment: *The charging circuit consists of a variable high - voltage power supply, a capacitor - charging circuit and an electrostatic 
voltmeter. Testing  is  begun  at  0.25  joule. A  0.02  microfarad  capacitor  is  connected  to  the  discharge  circuit  and charged to 5 kV.* - so, an equivalent of a static charge; very low power but high voltage. Possibly a piezzo crystal could be helpful. I'll try to compile an answer when I have the time. There's another paper: http://campus.mst.edu/aplab/index_files/AIAA-2015-4185.pdf

Comment: @SF. OK that's great thanks! The trail leads to both the term, and the company name *[Digital Solid State Propulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Solid_State_Propulsion)*. Any web site that can combine *Frank Zappa* and *Plasma Cannons* is worth a read in my book. fyi: There's a section on the use of arrays of small thrusters in the [SpinSsat Mission Overview](http://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2911&context=smallsat).

Comment: One beautiful thing there seems it's not just *restartable*. It can be "restarted" and "extinguished" up to 60 times per second. Which in practice means full throttlability,

Comment: @SF. I have a feeling it's a bit "noisy" - there may be significant variation the impulse that each pulse produces. So force transducers or feedback from attitude measurements may be necessary. Monopropellant thrusters have such a long and wide base of characterization they can be used with at least some level of precision and predictability. I know that [this 2009 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPOiDQ1-LuA) from the article Wired ["'Dial-a-Blast' Rocket Fuel'](https://www.wired.com/2009/05/video-dial-a-blast-rocket-fuel/) is 7 years old, I'm sure it's smoother looking now.

Comment: @uhoh -- Another possible interpretation (admittedly cynical) is that Digital Solid State Propulsion, LLC is a "one trick pony" whose one trick is writing winning SBIR contracts.

Comment: @DavidHammen A bit of cynicism is always appropriate re: government programs. Now I'm trying to find out: [Was actually happened to SpinSat - was the mission successful?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/16944/12102) I'm hoping that at least occasionally something started as an SBIR has eventually led to something useful. If a university professor gets money from the govt. to do research with no clear utility, it's considered scholarly work. Maybe it's OK for small, high tech companies on US soil to do the same. Like the slogan for the New York Lottery says: "*Hey, you never know.®*"

Comment: @David: The idea isn't *that* outlandish. A material with lower burning temperature than ignition temperature (non-self-sustaining flame, like a [tertiary explosive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive_material#Tertiary_explosive)); a source of ignition (electric spark), an isolator that evaporates in high temperature, two electrodes, power, that's all. The rest is perfecting the chemical formulas and engineering a good package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basing on two papers I had managed to find:  [Electrical Solid Propellants:
A Safe, Micro to Macro Propulsion Technology](http://dsspropulsion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ESP_Safe_Micro_To_Macro-Website.pdf) and [Plasma Plume Characterization of Electric Solid Propellant Pulsed Microthrusters](http://campus.mst.edu/aplab/index_files/AIAA-2015-4185.pdf).

First, the concept isn't new; it's an incremental research on [Pulsed Plasma Thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsed_plasma_thruster) which were used first on soviet Zond 2 and Zond 3, starting in 1964. In Pulsed Plasma Thrusters, all the combustion energy comes from electric discharge, which evaporates a small portion of inert (non-combustible) solid propellant (usually teflon), the process producing a "puff" of charged plasma (moving at relatively low speed), which is subsequently propelled through ion engine principles.

The Electric Solid Propellant (ESP) does away with the ion engine part, but instead uses an *almost* combustible (just barely self-extinguishing) propellant which evaporates rapidly enough to produce a reasonable exhaust velocity. It also replaces moving propellant stick and the fixed "spark plug" electrode with a non-movable structure of electrodes, conductive (but resistive enough to create plasma) propellant and ablating insulator, ablation of which (during combustion of the propellant) exposes more of the electrode, allowing the electric pulse to travel with the front of the propellant.

[image: structure, as described above; bisection: concentrically - inner electrode (tube), ESP, insulator, outer electrode.]

There is a number of different ESPs, varying in properties

- ASPEN - an early formulation; response time of order of 0.1s, may be difficult to extinguish after achieving higher pressures
- HIPEP - minimum smoke, non-metalized, good burning rate and ignitability properties, wide temperature range
- ESP ANAV - high aluminum content, high insensitivity to hazards (flame, spark, impact, friction), can self-sustain after ignition (though electricity still regulates burn rate).
- BADB - similarly, can self-sustain and offer better performance, but require additional processing to passivate surface active characteristics to
  retain acceptable storage and service life.

Specific impulse in all these is on par, or somewhat below that found in classic SRBs - of order of 200-230s. The primary differences are in smoke signature, environmental vulnerability and ignitability characteristics.

Thanks to the plastisol process, they can be prepared with standard lab equipment and just "cast"  like resins and the likes - simply poured into the prepared thruster, in room temperature. "Curing" occurs in temperatures of order of 35C over 7 days. This way, for example, microthruster modules are prepared. Such modules can be installed directly in nanosatellites.

[image: single microthrusters, and six-microthruster modules]

The microthrusters like pictured above can fire for 1.5s, providing 5-10 millinewtons of thrust (x6 in the sextuple modules). The microthrusters can be activated in very short pulses - of order of 0.02s or less, to provide a fine regulation of impulse.

Of course the propellant can also be used in larger assemblies.

[image]

Currently, a *test article* microsatellite "SpinSat" utilizing the microthrusters was launched from ISS on 28th November 2014. The results have [not been published yet](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/16946/103).

30-12-2022 edit: Integza has released a video where he talks with creators of ESP and experiments with it:

Comment: This sounds like something that might be produced on a 3D printer

Comment: @HowardMiller: Not simply; all that copper for electrodes etc. But I could picture a giant electronics manufacturer making such microthrusters next to capacitors, coils and fuses; they really look like parts to be soldered into a PCB.