# Does this electronics box, or any other non-spacecraft released by astronauts have a TLE?

Tags: artificial-satellite, two-line-elements, eva

According to Space.com's 02-Feb-2018 article [Cosmonauts Break Russian Spacewalk Record During Space Station Antenna Repair](https://www.space.com/39583-cosmonauts-break-russian-spacewalk-time-record.html):

> The cosmonauts spent the day replacing an electronics box for a high-gain communications antenna outside the Zvezda service module. Instead of holding on to the outdated piece of equipment, the cosmonauts tossed the original electronics box overboard, dooming it to burn up in Earth's atmosphere.
>
> **caption:** An old electronics box drifts through space after Russian cosmonauts tossed it away from the International Space Station during a spacewalk on Feb. 2, 2018. Credit: NASA TV

[image]

---

Many cubesats have been deployed from the ISS, and at least one "[spheresat](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16944/12102)"  as well. These would all have publicly available [Two Line Elements Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) (TLEs). However I'm not so sure about [suitsats or toolbagsats](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17741/12102).

Have objects released manually by astronauts (intentionally or otherwise) ever had publicly available TLEs that could be looked up?

[image: "suitsat"] [image: "toolbagsat"]

[image: "spheresat" actually spinsat]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 330 objects with an international designation starting with 1998-067, the first of which is the ISS. All of these are associated with the ISS, either being intentional or unintentional satellites released, or other related objects. Many of these are called "ISS Deb". It can be difficult to trace exactly which one corresponds to a particular object, and they also sometimes don't seem to show up right away.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Searching for both `1998-067`and `DEB` conveniently finds a bit more than 100 debris objects associated with the ISS, all except three of which have reentry dates. However I'll have to think of another strategy for debris manually released by astronauts from other platforms. This Space SE stuff never ends!