# When would the density Isp product be an important performance metric of a propellant?

Tags: fuel, specific-impulse, performance, monopropellant

The quote

> [NASA is testing hydroxylammonium nitrate in space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Propellant_Infusion_Mission) which is expected to perform 50% better than standard propellants and can be allowed to freeze (hydrazine must be kept liquid). [LMP-103S has been tested](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/9679/4704) gets about 30%.

used in [Why would it be “less bad” for hydroxylammonium nitrate monopropellant to freeze than for hydrazine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37894/12102)
 and found in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37893/12102) to *Is the EU really banning “toxic propellants” in 2020? How is that going to work?* raised [a question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/why-would-it-be-less-bad-for-hydroxylammonium-nitrate-monopropellant-to-freeze?noredirect=1#comment120936_37894) about how a monopropellant could be 50% better than hydrazine.

The reply comment links to [GPIM AF-M315E Propulsion System](https://www.rocket.com/sites/default/files/documents/CubeSat/GPIM%20AF-M315E%20Propulsion%20System.pdf) which explains that the performance metric is the product of density and Isp.

**Question:** When would the density Isp product be an important performance metric of a propellant?

Answer (score 5):

From the [ECAPS page on LMP-103S performance](http://ecaps.space/hpgp-performance.php)...

> The specific impulse is ≥ 6% higher and the propellant density is 24% higher. As a result, ***the satellite can either be fitted with a smaller tank, or the mission duration can be extended while retaining the same tank size.***

Volume is important because you only have so much room inside a [payload fairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_fairing). Propellant available for [station keeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_station-keeping) and maneuvering is a limit on the lifespan of a spacecraft.

Comment: Thanks! This might also apply to smallsats of fixed size, e.g. ambitious 3U cubesats.

Comment: fyi I just realized that "HAN" is another name for hydroxylammonium nitrate, and so it seems I've questioned about its use in cubesats before! [Is HAN-water propellant “green” enough to ever be used in a cubesat?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18838/12102)

Answer (score 5):

> When would the density Isp product be an important performance metric of a propellant?

It's always important.

Specific impulse is a measure of impulse provided per mass unit of combusted propellant, which is a great metric for fuel-efficency in a rocket. However, it doesn't take into account the mass of things other than fuel -- like fuel tankage, which has mass generally proportional to its volume.

Hydrogen, for example, looks vastly better than kerosene if you just look at specific impulse, but it is about 1/15 as dense, so some of the specific impulse advantage is lost due to requiring much more tankage volume.

Density-Isp-product isn't a mathematically "correct" metric for comparing propellants -- you'd need a spreadsheet and information about tankage structure, pressure, etc. to actually compute a correct metric -- but it could be useful for identifying interesting candidate propellants before moving onto the spreadsheet phase of the contest.

Comment: …well, fuel tank mass is _exponential_ to its volume, with the exponent varying by tank shape. But most people get the point of what you posted.

Answer (score 4):

While it isn't precisely *space exploration* per se, John Clark mentions this being important in *Ignition* for missiles, especially in cases when it is desired to meet a performance goal while having a missile meet some imposed or preexisting form factor, and some of the weirdest extremes of his and others' work (done for the Navy) described in *Ignition* focused on largely doomed attempts at fuels with moderate Isp and very high density.

Modern-day space exploration is often able to make very lightweight tanks (suitable, among other things, for LH2) but there are many times when one does not want a space vehicle to resemble a water balloon, especially if it must fit in a fairing or aeroshell or undergo atmospheric flight.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I see.

Let's say I am building an ambitious 3U cubesat and I've allocated 1U for fuel and 2U for payload and bus, and I want to select the propellant that will give me the most delta-v.

I don't know [Cubesat mass density (kg/U) statistics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32289/12102) but lets say I've got a 3 kg (dry mass $m_D$) 3U cubesat with a 1 liter tank. What is the delta-v as a function of $I_{sp}$ and $\rho$ with a fixed tank volume $V$? Applying tyrannical [Tsiolkovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) we get:

$$\Delta v = I_{sp} g_0 \ln \frac{m_D+\rho V}{m_D} = I_{sp} g_0 \ln \left(1 + \frac{\rho V}{m_D}\right).$$

Remember that the log of 1 plus something small is approximately that thing (i.e. $\ln(1+x) \approx x$ for small $x$)

$$\Delta v \approx I_{sp} g_0 \frac{\rho V}{m_D} = I_{sp}\rho  \frac{g_0 V}{m_D}.$$

The density specific impulse product $I_{sp}\rho$ **is the predictor of total delta-v possible when the tank volume is fixed**, and the relationship is simple linear when the propellant mass is a small fraction of the total spacecraft mass.

For [flying fuel tanks](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23026/12102) you'll need to keep the logarithm in the expression and so while close, the highest $I_{sp}\rho$ product monopropellant may not have exactly the highest $\Delta v$. *checking now...*

Comment: The logarithm is a concave function, so for a fixed $I_{sp}\rho$ product (and the same dry mass and tank volume), scaling $I_{sp}$ up and $\rho$ down by the same factor will increase $\Delta v$. Which makes sense — you're still getting the same total impulse (i.e. change in momentum) from burning the fuel, but have less mass to push during the burn.