# Prop feed with Anhydrous Ammonia in Microgravity

Tags: propulsion, monopropellant, green-propellant, ammonia

Considering contributing to an SBIR through my PhD where we're looking at NH3 as a green prop solution.  Need to figure out how to feed vapor from a liquid/mixed phase tank to the a prop system.  Could we just open a valve and have a vaporizer inline to ensure no blobs of liquid get through to the prop feed system?  My thought here is that if you have a tank of liquid NH3 on orbit and open a valve, it's going to blow down to vacuum whether it's sputtering liquid blobs or not.

Would a PMD or some other prop management be advisable?  Any literature or research that's available?

Thanks!

Comment: There are other questions about ammonia (and related compounds) that may contain some information that could be helpful here as well: [Reasons why liquid anhydrous ammonia fuel chosen for the X-15? Has it been used in other rocket engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22758/12102) and also [What kind of engine does this Isp = 1600 refer to? Is it cubesat-friendly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18802/12102) (ammonia, ammonium nitrate and HAN) and also [Is HAN-water propellant “green” enough to ever be used in a cubesat?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18838/12102) (HAN only)

Comment: Thanks @uhoh I'll give those a read!