# How much thrust can plasma produced from water have?

Tags: propulsion

If water could be converted to plasma for a propellant by electricity how much thrust would water produce? What would be the byproduct?

Comment: If you build a huge engine, you can get much thrust even when using a low energy fuel.

Comment: What exactly does "converted to plasma for a propellant by electricity" mean? Arcjets do make *some plasma* but the function there is for heating by passing a large current through it. But that just makes it hot, the same way burning makes things hot. The arcjet produces thrust by expansion in a nozzle, and so the propulsive actions are not related to electricity. Since you've got a nice answer for that process, if you'd like to ask about *electric propulsion* using water, maybe you should ask separately.

Comment: Of course you can see your own edit history: click this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKr6i.png then click this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVxkY.png

Comment: I'm glad to see the question restored to its original form, and the excellent answer now restored as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an [arcjet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcjet_rocket).

Like other electrically-powered rockets, the thrust of an arcjet is quite low, but the [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse) is good. Hydrazine, ammonia, and hydrogen are the most-often proposed propellants for arcjets, but [water has been used experimentally as well](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290513459_Stability_and_performance_experiment_in_a_water_arcjet) (paywalled paper, so I don't actually know the thrust value they got). Specific impulse is around 500-600 seconds; thrust would be on the order of 100-200 Newton per megawatt of power input. The exhaust would be water in some form or another -- water vapor, droplets, or some combination.

Comment: This is how arcjets work: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18837/12102 Can you cite a source showing that "water has been used as well"?

Comment: @uhoh *sighs in late capitalism* yeah, link added, and clarifying that water arcjets are experimental.

Comment: Also I think I slipped a few digits in the thrust value there.

Comment: Thanks! So not so much "used" as "addressed" or "contemplated" or "investigated".

Comment: "Water has been used in an arcjet thruster" was what I was trying to say, not "water arcjet thrusters have been used on flown spacecraft".

Comment: `The exhaust would be water in some form or another -- water vapor, droplets` => So, not plasma... This doesn't answer the question as stated.

Comment: @Antzi - Some of the water may be ionized (= plasma) in the chamber, but I expect the electrons would reassociate quite quickly on exit.

Comment: This is true of arcjets but it doesn't really provide a full answer to the (rather vague) question.