# Does a feasible high thrust high specific impulse engine exist using current non space technology?

Tags: advanced-propulsion

What I mean is an engine whose thrust is on the order of tens to hundreds of Newtons with an ISP "well" above that of chemical engines. I don't require this engine to be space ready - if it has to plug into a mega watt generator and only works on the ground at the moment that's fine - but it must be buildable with current technology. That means that fusion power or antimatter is out.  I'm ok with an engine that has been proposed but not built, or an engine that is low thrust but only because it has never been scaled up.

I do require the engine to at least have been peer reviewed and simulated in a high fidelity simulation.

So, doors such an engine concept exist?

Comment: I thought I had one: [What kind of engine does this Isp = 1600 refer to? Is it cubesat-friendly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18802/12102) but the thrust turns out to be a hundred *milli-newtons."

Comment: A cluster of any ion engine we used so far will do - they offer about 50N from your 1 MW generator.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to talk about Newtons here. Cluster enough engines of any type and you'll hit that. Perhaps thrust-to-mass ratio instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [NERVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NERVA)?

NERVA (Nuclear Engine for Rocket Vehicle Application) was a nuclear-thermal engine.  A reactor heated hydrogen propellant and exhausted it out the nozzle.

The engine was extensively and successfully ground tested.

[image]

Thrust ~ 250 kN

ISP ~ 840

(You didn't mention political considerations or thrust-to-weight ratio)

Comment: Nah, the T/W of NERVA is fine while not amazing. This would also fall under "low thrust but only because it has never been scaled up", since there are still considerable scaling gains.

Comment: I can live with NERVA, yes.  I was hoping for something more modern/politically possible but that wasn't really specified in the question

Comment: If you need a data point for how such an engine may scale *down*, the smaller [rd-0410](http://astronautix.com/r/rd-0410.html) was also extensively tested.

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky [Project Timberwind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Timberwind) was the next generation nuclear-thermal -- no more political feasible but slightly more modern.

Comment: I'm coining a new phrase and claiming ownership: "thrust-to-dose ratio".

Answer (score 4):

In general, [thermal rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_rocket) can in theory have very good $I_{SP}$ (around 1000s), and provide high thrust.

Unlike chemical rockets, which by definition produce heavy exhaust gasses like $CO_2$, $CO$ or $H_2O$, a thermal rocket can pick any propellant. That would mean it's possible to eject pure hydrogen gas (which in the hotter cases will start to disassociate into mono-atomic hydrogen). The advantage of this is that lighter gasses have higher exhaust velocities at equal temperatures. A thermal rocket is limited by what temperature the engine can stand.

But eliminating the chemical reaction leaves the engine without an energy source for the heat. Some options:

- Using a reactor, Organic Marble's example.
- Concentrated solar power.
- Lasers from Earth.

On the ground, we could hook it up to the grid.

Comment: factoid: lighter atoms (with +1 charge) also have higher Isp at a given acceleration voltage ($\sim m^{-1/2}$)